# EXCEL url to domain

Tags: excel

i have been searching and working at this for several hours now.

I currently have a formula that converts URL's to domains (column B), but it is unable to handle domains such as "co.uk" the formula also should not rely on the presence of "www" or "http://" on the upside there is no information after the TLD (.com, .co.uk, etc)

> example.com results in **example.com**
>
> test.example.com results in **example.com**
>
> www.example.com results in **example.com**
>
> example.co.uk results in **co.uk** which is wrong
>
> www.example.ab.kr results in **ab.kr** which is also wrong
>
> example.ab.kr results in **ab.kr** which is also wrong

the current excel formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE(REPLACE(A1, 1, IFERROR(FIND("//", A1)+1, 0), TEXT(,))&"/", FIND("/", REPLACE(A1, 1, IFERROR(FIND("//", A1)+1, 0), TEXT(,))&"/"), LEN(A1), TEXT(,)), CHAR(46), REPT(CHAR(32), LEN(A1))), LEN(A1)*2)), CHAR(32), CHAR(46))
```

does anyone have any thoughts on how to make sure the output includes any of the combinations? as my name eludes; i am average in excel and need your help :P

Answer (score 0):

Without going into too much detail: the problem with the function you've included is that it removes any text to the left of the second period (".", aka ASCII 46) in the original string. The function assumes that the second period in a URL is a reliable indication for where the domain name ends (which, based on the examples you provided, is clearly not the case).

While we *could* try to modify your function to handle such cases, there's a function that I use always for stripping URLs down to domains:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("www.",A1)),MID(A1,FIND("www.",A1)+4,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("/",A1,9)),FIND("/",A1,9),LEN(A1)+1)-FIND("www.",A1)-4),MID(A1,FIND("//",A1)+2,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("/",A1,9)),FIND("/",A1,9),LEN(A1)+1)-FIND("//",A1)-2))`

([source](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2028-excel-extract-domain-from-url.html))

The above function does have a caveat: the original URL must contain either "www." or "//". The lazy workaround I found for this is as follows:

1. Use the following function to add "http://" to all URLs that do not contain "//":

`=IF(ISNUMBER(IFERROR(FIND("//", A2, 1), "X")), A2, "http://"&A2)`

2. Use the first function mentioned above to strip the URL down to the domain.

[Here's an example (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ08H.png)

Though it is a bit contrived, it should work properly, and I'm a bit scared to start messing with the original function.

Comment: I see, it does work and i think i have tried this one before. but it only seems to operate when there is a www. in the URL. and in my case i have 700.000 Urls to convert and a lot of them are like: "translate.google.co.uk
".

Comment: you relply is very appreciated though :) i hope you have another thought. i will look in to how i can avoid that use of the second period. :)

Comment: i updated the question to better represent the actual data.

Comment: You are right in that the function uses "//" or "www." to find where the domain starts. The quickest workaround I could think of would be to use the following function to add "http://" at the beginning of every URL that starts with neither "www." nor "//": =IF(ISNUMBER(IFERROR(FIND("//", A2, 1), "X")), A2, "http://"&A2)

Comment: The function I wrote above will add "http://" to any URL where that would be necessary, and do nothing to the URLs that work fine with the original function I included in my answer.

Comment: Would that function also work in case of a subdomain? e.g. "test.example.com" results in "example.com"?

Comment: I've edited my original answer in accordance with what I've written in the comments. Unfortunately, it cannot strip subdomains, but I'll try to work out how that can be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function domain(s As String) As String
    Dim ss As String, pats(1 To 5) As String
    Dim i As Long

    pats(1) = "http://www."
    pats(2) = "https://www."
    pats(3) = "http://"
    pats(4) = "https://"
    pats(5) = "www."
    ss = s

    For i = 1 To 5
        If InStr(1, ss, pats(i)) = 1 Then ss = Replace(ss, pats(i), "")
    Next i

    arr = Split(ss, "/")
    domain = arr(0)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this one, unfortunately this cannot handle subdomains such as "test.example.com". Thanks for thinking along with me :)

Comment: @Average_Excel_Guru  Please update your original question with a **specific** example of both input and desired output for which the *UDF()* fails..............I will fix it.